# Applying fundamental theorem of calculus in a tricky case

Tags: calculus

A simple application of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus (FTC) as a reminder: $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_x^\infty f(t)dt=-f(x)$$
What if the integrand $f$ also depends on $x$? 
So $$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\int_x^\infty f(t,x)dt$$ then how do we apply the FTC?

Could it be that it just equals to $-f(x,x)$?

---- Solution according to @P. Lawrence's answer----

Applying the Leibniz's Rule as suggested and correcting derivative notation gives
$$\frac{d}{d x}\int_x^\infty f(t,x)dt=\lim_{b\rightarrow\infty}\int_x^\infty \frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)dt-f(x,x)$$

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_x^{\infty}f(t,x)dt$$ is a function just of $x$, not of $t$, which is only a dummy variable, living only inside the integral.

You should write $\frac{d}{dx}$, not $\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and you need Leibniz's Rule 
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}f(t,x)dt=\int_{u(x)}^{v(x)}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}f(t,x)dt+f(v(x),x)v'(x)-f(u(x),x)u'(x)$$
Now put 
$$u(x)=x\\v(x)=b$$ so $$u'(x)=1\\v'(x)=0$$ and take the limit as $b \rightarrow \infty $, provided the limit exists.

Comment: Thanks, this does the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Let us define a function $G(y,x)$ as 
$$G(y,x)=\int_y^\infty f(t,x) \,dt.$$
Note that
$$\partial_y G(y,x)=-f(y,x),$$
and 
$$\partial_x G(y,x)=\int_y^\infty \partial_x f(t,x)\,dt.$$
Let $y(x)=x$. Then, by the total defferentiation (See "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative"),
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{y(x)}^\infty f(t,x) \,dt&= \frac{d}{dx} G(y(x),x)\\
&=\partial_y G(y(x),x) \frac{dy}{dx}+ \partial_y G(y(x),x)\\
&=-f(y(x),x)+\int_{y(x)}^\infty \partial_x f(t,x)\,dt\\
&=-f(x,x)+\int_{x}^\infty \partial_x f(t,x)\,dt.
\end{align*}
Does it answer your question?

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. This showed that using total derivative we arrive at the same conclusion as Leibniz's Rule gives.